# Positioning rotated letters inside viewBox in svg

Tags: svg

I have code which generates svg (by means of producing the XML DOM). It takes input text and randomly scatters it's letters on page as shown below.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <!-- ... styles omitted -->
    <text x="20" y="150" rotate="45">M</text>    
    <text x="100" y="80" rotate="45">W</text>        
    <text x="90" y="50" rotate="270">X</text>
    <!-- etc ... -->
</svg>
```

I have problem how to fill the page efficiently without having letters extend outside of the view box. Either I limit the random values for the x and y, but then there is lot of space left empty around borders. Or I use wider ranges for x,y but then the letters bleed outside. As show the red letters in the jsfiddle example (https://jsfiddle.net/5zqrugx1/1/).
I tried to adjust the x, y ranges based on rotation, but still it does not help much because of different letter shapes.

I am looking for way to style/position these letters in svg in a way which would force them to be completely inside the view port while being able to fill the space border-to-border (this second condition added later to clarify). Something like giving 0-100% where 0% would mean "touching left border" and 100% would be "touching right border". Is there any way to do it?

Below is example which I hand-edited to achieve more-less desired result.

[image: Sample (hand-edited) result]

Answer (score 2):

What this probably amounts to is controling the center of rotation in such a way that it is in the center of the glyph. This way, all you need is a 0.5em padding at each edge.

You can start out with positioning the text control point at the middle both horizontally and vertically:

```
text {
    text-anchor:middle;
    dominant-baseline:middle;
}
```

Unfortunately, using the `rotate` attribute of the `text` element does not work as expected (at least in Firefox). But you can get around that by adding a post-rotation via a `transform` attribute. The best way to formulate it would be to also position the glyph with a translation:

```
<text transform="translate(40 100) rotate(60)">A</text>
```

Order is important - `translate` must come before `rotate`.

The following example rotates all glyphs around the center of the circles they are sitting in. It turns out the font-defined `middle` is a bit off, so you have to tweak with a `dy` attribute. If it shows still a bit wrong on your screen, this is because the font used by your system might define or compute a different middle line. For a system-independent experience, you would need to use a web font for you to have complete control.

```css
circle {
    fill: none;
    stroke: blue;
}
text {
    text-anchor: middle;
    dominant-baseline: middle;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 350 100">
  <circle r="25" cx="50" cy="50" />
  <circle r="25" cx="100" cy="50" />
  <circle r="25" cx="150" cy="50" />
  <circle r="25" cx="200" cy="50" />
  <circle r="25" cx="250" cy="50" />
  <circle r="25" cx="300" cy="50" />
  <text dy="4" transform="translate(50 50) rotate(60)">A</text>
  <text dy="4" transform="translate(100 50) rotate(120)">B</text>
  <text dy="4" transform="translate(150 50) rotate(180)">C</text>
  <text dy="4" transform="translate(200 50) rotate(240)">D</text>
  <text dy="4" transform="translate(250 50) rotate(300)">E</text>
  <text dy="4" transform="translate(300 50) rotate(360)">F</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The text-anchor is useful for making the rotation more predictable (turns out that dominant-baseline is not needed, as each baseline needs dy correction anyway). However it turns out that using the circumscribed circle radius as the safety distance is too conservative - it results in large gaps around border (e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/3nykgt8x/1/). So it's definitely improvement, but not the complete solution.

Comment: Maybe a bit pedantic, but your question gave no indication what a success criterium would be. My answer contains exactly the same amount of guesswork about your goals as your question contains inaccuracy.

Comment: Fair point, it was indirectly implied by the dream solution ("touching left/right border"), but not stated explicitly - I added it now. Still thank you for the answer though, it helped me to learn something.